# playing a sound, waiting it to finish playing and continue (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

i'm new with the iphone and objective c, so far, I have been able to code some small examples.

i would like to play a sound and, continue with rest of the code when the sample finishes playing, i.e:

```
printf("hello");
playASound["file.wav"];
printf("world");
```

actually i'm getting: print hello, play the file and print world at the same time
but 
what i want is: print hello, play the file, print world... 
so, the question is how do i get it?

thanks

btw. here is the playASound code:

```
-(void) playASound: (NSString *) file {

    //Get the filename of the sound file:
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                      file];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    //Get a URL for the sound file
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
    //play the file
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound):

> Discussion This function plays a short
>   sound (30 seconds or less in
>   duration). Because sound might play
>   for several seconds, this function is
>   executed asynchronously. To know when
>   a sound has finished playing, call the
>   AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion
>   function to register a callback
>   function.

So you'll need to break up your function into two pieces: a function that calls PlayASound and prints "Hello", and a function that is [called by the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_function#Use) when the sound is finished playing and prints "World".

```
// Change PlayASound to return the SystemSoundID it created
-(SystemSoundID) playASound: (NSString *) file {

    //Get the filename of the sound file:
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                      file];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    //Get a URL for the sound file
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
    //play the file
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    return soundID;
}

-(void)startSound
{
   printf("Hello");
    SystemSoundID id = [self playASound:@"file.wav"];
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (
       id,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       endSound,
       NULL
   );
}

void endSound (
   SystemSoundID  ssID,
   void           *clientData
)
{
   printf("world\n");
}
```

See also [docs for AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion) and [AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc).

Comment: Does "path" get automatically released?